# How to use library a.k.a jointjs together with Cycle.js

Tags: javascript, jointjs, cyclejs

Recently I was looking for an framework that I can use together with jointjs. So far I tried react/angular/angular2.

I do wanna try out it with Cycle.js. But putting them together so 'old' stuff (jointjs) and cycle.js just overheads me. I know that I should create a driver to interact with jointjs. If someone can help me to get starter with simple example of joint(e.g.: http://www.jointjs.com/tutorial#hello-world) + cycle, that would be amazing.

Basic points that need to be included is:

1. JointJS required an container NODE element
2. Whenever users makes some changes (drag&drops elements around or resize them) it will broadcast an event. Something like this:

> ```
> graph.on('all', function(eventName, cell) {
>     console.log(arguments);
> });
> ```

Comment: What prevents you from trying? The 'old' stuff is still javascript. Have you read the docs for cycle.js ?? What is 'overheading' you. Maybe you should try to actually do something by yourself, and ask more specific questions when you encounter an issue.

Comment: There was couple questions, which I had to solve. 1. How to pass DOM element to driver. 2. How to load initially diagram into jointjs. 3. Where to define config stage for jointjs.

Luckily I solved most of them. Will post an solution later here.

Comment: That would be great and allow you to get comment on the code regarding the points 1-3 you mentioned.